R' Amar's Heter on Neuter/Spaying Pets
This article from Chai Online cites a psak from R' Shlomo Amar, then Rishon leTzion, that spaying or neutering a companion animal or pet is not forbidden under the general prohibition against mutilating animals, due to a concern of tza'ar ba'alei chaim (causing unnecessary suffering to animals).
Due to the Torah prohibition of castration, this seems a bit far-fetched to me, especially considering that the above article seems quite intent on instructing people to neuter or spay their animals. (see Shulchan 'Aruch Even ha'Ezer  5:11)
Does R' Amar actually permit neutering a companion animal or pet and what reasoning does he bring?

Aside from private sales of pet owners often when you buy or adopt a pet in the us the surgery is done before the animal belongs to you.

@Dude, I know that this is the case for rescues, but I'm not sure that it's true of all cases here. Keep in mind that there are other countries and R' Amar is presumably ruling for Israelis, where many of our leniencies in Chu"L don't exist
